# Using MQTT over websockets with Ionic4 + Angular after authentication with AWS cognito

Tags: angular, ionic4, aws-sdk-js

I am creating an Android application using Ionic4 + Angular + Capacitor and want to communicate with AWS Iot Core (MQTT and Things shadow). In the application I can't use certificates so I used AWS amplify library and I am successfully able to login using it. But now I want to send/receive messages over MQTT and update things shadow using MQTT client. I used PubSub (AWSIotProvider). Sometimes I miss few packets from the broker and in library, there is no option to set QOS level. How to specify the QOS for the connections to broker?

I found aws-iot-device-sdk, aws-sdk (npm). But I don't know how to integrate these with AWS Amplify Auth service after authentication. I am only allowing authenticated users to access Iot core services. I also tried MqttOverWSProvider but it also doesn't allow qos levels.

```
Amplify.addPluggable(new MqttOverWSProvider(
{
   aws_pubsub_region: 'us-abcd-2',
   aws_pubsub_endpoint: 'wss://z38kftsj5d9fabc-ats.iot.us-abcd-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt'
}));
PubSub.subscribe(topicName).subscribe({next..., error ..., close})
```

MqttOverWSProvider problem : AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined

I have already done authentication and authorization using AWS Cognito. Now I want to use those credentials for MQTT in my Ionic4 application using Angular and Typescript.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js here? You will need to creat the policy and attach the user to this policy. (as its descibed)